# Batch File Script Issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, command-line-arguments

At my work we use a batch file for restarting services in the evenings. But there are a few issues. 1 is that when the batch runs, in the command prompt there's an error message that says: `ERROR: The process "nameofservice.exe" not found.` A couple of times and then it closes and finishes. This isn't too big of an issue but I've noticed that in some cases that error message will display continually and it never closes.

The other issue I run into, and too my knowledge this has only started happening recently, is that the batch script is running continually. It's supposed to go through and restart all of the listed services once, then stop. But after restarting them all it just starts again. I've had to set it to terminate after 6 hours (the script should hardly take 20 mins) in the task scheduler.

Here's the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->> liblog.txt
ECHO -----------========================----------->> liblog.txt
ECHO -----------=========%date%=========----------->> liblog.txt
ECHO -----------========================----------->> liblog.txt
ECHO ---------------------------------------------->> liblog.txt

set DD=0
Set TIMESTAMP="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
For /F %TIMESTAMP% %%i in ('DATE /t') DO (
    SET YYYYMMDD=%%l%%j%%k
    SET YYYYMM=%%l%%j
    set DD=%%k
)

echo C2 >> libservers
echo G >> libservers
echo H >> libservers
echo I >> libservers
echo J >> libservers
echo K >> libservers
echo L >> libservers
echo M >> libservers
echo N >> libservers
echo O >> libservers
echo P >> libservers
echo Q >> libservers
echo R >> libservers
echo S >> libservers
echo T >> libservers
echo U >> libservers
echo V >> libservers
echo W >> libservers
echo X >> libservers
echo Y >> libservers
echo Z >> libservers

for /f %%a in (libservers) do (
    set timestamp=!date!!time!
    ECHO !timestamp! - Stopping Libserver %%a >> liblog.txt
    net stop /y NuCPLibServerFB_%%a >> liblog.txt
    taskkill /f /im NuCPLibServerFB_%%a.exe >> liblog.txt

    ping localhost -n 30 > nul

    if %DD%==01 (
        ren D:\Libserver\Logs\LibServer_Server%%a.GDB LibServer_Server%%a_%yyyymm%.GDB >> liblog.txt
        copy D:\Libserver\Logs\LibServer_Server.GDB     D:\Libserver\Logs\LibServer_Server%%a.GDB
    )
    set timestamp=!date!!time!
    ECHO !timestamp! - Starting Libserver %%a >> liblog.txt
    net start NuCPLibServerFB_%%a >> liblog.txt
)

for /f %%a in (libservers) do (
    set timestamp=!date!!time!
    ECHO !timestamp! - Stopping Libserver %%a >> liblog.txt
    net stop /y NuCPLibServerFB_%%a >> liblog.txt
    taskkill /f /im NuCPLibServerFB_%%a.exe >> liblog.txt

    ping localhost -n 30 > nul

    set timestamp=!date!!time!
    ECHO !timestamp! - Starting Libserver %%a >> liblog.txt
    net start NuCPLibServerFB_%%a >> liblog.txt
)
if exist libservers del libserversrs
```

Unfortunately I'm not the one who wrote it so I don't understand how it works thoroughly, I'm still learning this stuff.

Any help is appreciated. I'm not looking for a magic fix, just some help figuring out why it's not working and any suggestions to look at that might improve it.

Comment: The first thing I see is that it sends a stop message to a service, kills the process the service uses, waits 30 seconds and then starts the service. That isn't very good practice since there is no time between stopping the service and killing the process. the `SC` command is more robust for this type of thing. So is `WMIC`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this isn't really a site for "Here's a dump of code. Fix it for me?" type questions. We're happy to help answer specific questions if we can, but we can't be expected to figure out what you're asking, debug your code to find out what's wrong, and fix it for you. If you can narrow it down to a reasonable scope, explain exactly how it isn't working, and ask a single specific question, we can try to help.

Comment: No problem Ken I wasn't expecting a magic fix just some suggestions as to why it isn't behaving as expected. Matt, I thank you for the sc command suggestion. I've tried replacing the net start/stop and taskkill commands with sc start and sc stop and so far in testing it's working beautifully.